# Enabling "elide" property in the QML Text element, but in a GridLayout

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I understand the "width" property must be set implicitly for `elide` to work. However, I have a `Text` element in a Layout. I would like to truncate the text when it gets too long. How can I use `elide` in a Text type when it is in a GridLayout?

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1


Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height: 20

    GridLayout {
        clip: true
        anchors.fill: parent

        rows: 1

        Text{
           text: "veryverylooooooonnnnnnnnnnnggggggggggggggtext"
           width: 50

           elide: Text.ElideRight
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change `width: 50` to `Layout.preferredWidth: 50`

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height: 20
    GridLayout {
        clip: true
        anchors.fill: parent
        rows: 1
        Text {
           text: "veryverylooooooonnnnnnnnnnnggggggggggggggtext"
           Layout.preferredWidth: 50
           elide: Text.ElideRight
        }
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]